# Get position of dragged element

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

On finger move, I want to know the position of the view dragged after `startDrag()` call.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event, int position)
{
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
}
```

Is it possible?